# MouseEvent with modifier keys does not work in firefox, any work insight to why?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, mouseevent

I have been experimenting with [`MouseEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) recently and found a odd quirk when applying modifier key options.

Take the following example;

```
var elm = document.querySelector('a');
var options = {ctrlKey: true};
if(navigator.platform.indexOf('Mac') !== -1){
  options.ctrlKey = false;
  options.metaKey = true;
}
var evt = new MouseEvent('click', options);
elm.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

*Note: `metaKey` is for Mac OS X support to simulate the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key.*

It is expected to find the first anchor and then click on it with a modifier key set (in this case the anchor href will open in a new window).

I have tested this in Google Chrome and it works as expected. However in Mozilla Firefox, the event doesn't not emit.

It is interesting how Firefox doesn't support this but it is documented to work as expected.

Have you come across this issue before and if there any work arounds are possible?